# convert animation nodes data to editable objects?

Tags: animation-nodes

How to to convert animation nodes result into an object?

For example, I have a project in which I use animation nodes to get final result, but the baked result is only in my computer.

When i try to to render this on network the result would change, so I want to convert it into mesh and render it on a system where animation node is not installed.